# Need fulltext searches to function similar to LIKE %...%

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

I need to search an ISBN column and allow partial matches to be returned. Using LIKE is accurate but very slow, about 2-3 seconds:

```
select * from Isbns where isbn like '%1234567890123%'
-- returns 1 result: 1234567890123

select * from Isbns where isbn like '%12345678%'
-- returns 2 results: 1234567890123, 1234567811111.
```

Using the fulltext index, the search is instant, however, too many results are returned.

```
select * from Isbns where freetext(isbn, '"1234567890123"')
-- returns thousands of results, such as the exact match of 1234567890123, 
-- but also fuzzy matches such as: 1234567770123, 1234567778883, etc.
```

You can see the main difference is that LIKE matches based on the wildcard at the beginning and end of the term, whereas FREETEXT (and also CONTAINS) matches terms based on their content as a whole, even when wrapped with `""`. Since almost all of our ISBNs start with the same few numbers, and have little variance in the following numbers, too many matches are being returned.

Is there a way to make FREETEXT or CONTAINS perform similar to LIKE, or any other way to utilize the fulltext index to search?

Answer (score 0):

If all your ISBNs start with the same few numbers, leave off the wildcard at the beginning of the string:

```
select *
from Isbns
where isbn like '12345678%';
```

Then be sure you have an index on `isbns(isbn)`.  Many databases will optimize the `like` when it begins with a constant.

Comment: I revised my question to read: "almost all" instead of "all". We have about 100 or so that start with random numbers. Sorry for the confusion, I only included that as an example of why there is such little variance between almost all of our ISBNs.